# Encrypt payload using a key and iv by AES/GCM/NoPadding algorithm in node js and decrypt in java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes-gcm

I have encrypt the file using node.js and decrypt in JAVA. Decryption is done in JAVA using "AES/GCM/Nopadding" algorithm and it is third party app hence I cannot see the JAVA code. 
I am encrypting the payload in node.js using "aes-128-gcm" algorithm.
for this, I am try mimicking a working java encryption code

I have tried with crypto and node-forge.
iam getting the output but am getting an error "Bad encryption - payload is not encrypted properly" when submitting payload.

pleas help me to find what I did wrong in this code.

working code in java

```
public void encrypt(@NonNull final byte[] payload, @NonNull final byte[] key) throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    SecretKeySpec codingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, AES);
    Cipher cipher = AEC_GCM_THREAD_CIPHER.get();
    byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    RANDOM.nextBytes(iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, codingKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    final byte[] encryptedPayload = cipher.doFinal(payload);
    byte[] encryptMerchantKey = encryptMerchantKey(key);

    String payloadFinal = encodeToUrlString(encryptedPayload);    // final payload
    String ivFinal =  encodeToUrlString(iv);                  // final iv
    String keyFinal =  encodeToUrlString(encryptMerchantKey);  // final key

    System.out.println("Payload");
    System.out.println(payloadFinal);
    System.out.println("iv");
    System.out.println(ivFinal);
    System.out.println("key");
    System.out.println(keyFinal);
}
```

code iam tried in node js

```
function encrypt(payload) {

    let key = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);
    let iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);

    let cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher("AES-GCM", key);
    cipher.start({ iv: iv});
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(payload));
    cipher.finish();

    let encrypted = forge.util.encode64(cipher.output.getBytes());
    let tag = forge.util.encode64(cipher.mode.tag.getBytes());
    let iv64 = forge.util.encode64(iv);

    let encryptedPayload = encrypted+tag;

    //RSA Encryption
    encryptedkey = RSAencrypt(forge.util.encode64(key));

     return {
     "payload" : base64url.fromBase64(encryptedPayload) ,
     "iv" : base64url.fromBase64(iv64).length,
     "key" : base64url.fromBase64(encryptedkey)
     };
}
```

Rsa description is working fine abling to decrypt the key.
some problem with aes encryption. as see the code, I added auth tag and encrypted data together but no use.

Comment: What does `toeknToUrlString` do? Why are you converting to base 64 only to decode it again in your NodeJS code? Note that the nonce (IV) of GCM has a default size of 12 bytes, not 16 and is therefore different from the block size (but 16 bytes nonce should be compatible none-the-less). Please *require* specifications from the accepting party, don't leave yourself guessing them!

Comment: You should also post output and don't let us generate that ourselves. Your Java clearly has output statements added to it, so where is it and why does your NodeJS not have the same kind of debugging statements?

Comment: "Bad encryption - payload is not encrypted properly" when submitting payload.

Comment: That's not the output of the function, that's the result of the side you've submitted it to (and since we don't even know how you submit the data we cannot even tell if that error is generated in the function you've shown us).

Comment: This is the error code i getting from third party. And baseurl string means iam converting base64 to baseurl methode . I didn't guessed iv value it is in the requirement.

Comment: Iam using postman to submit the payload iv and the key

Comment: Since you don't show even the slightest inclination on (learning) how to debug your own code, e.g. comparing the output of the functions to each other, I think we cannot help you here. This is not a minimal complete and verifyable example because it is *not complete* and it is missing input / output *as well* as the requirements for that input and output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198328/discussion-between-sharoon-ck-and-maarten-bodewes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with forge buffer it need to convert to node buffer
this code is working now. thanks, @Maarten Bodewes for the advice.

```
function encrypt(payload) {

    //initialize forge random buffer
    var key = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);
    var iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);

    let cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher("AES-GCM", key);
    cipher.start({iv : iv});
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(payload));
    cipher.finish();

    let encrypted = cipher.output.data;
    let tag = cipher.mode.tag.data;
    let encryptedLoad = encrypted+tag;

    // node buffer and forge buffer differ, so the forge buffer must be converted to node Buffer            
    iv = Buffer.from(iv, "binary");
    encryptedLoad = Buffer.from(encryptedLoad, "binary");

    //Calling RSA Encryption
    encryptedKey = RSAencrypt(key);

    return {
     "payload" : base64url(encryptedLoad) ,
     "iv" : base64url(iv),
     "key" : base64url.fromBase64(encryptedKey)
     };
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the java part to decode it as well ?

Answer (score 2):

I have complete example of encryption and decryption in angular and java you can take this example as it is and make changes according to you.
Install node-forge with command "npm install node-forge".

```
encrypt(msg, pass) {
    const key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(8).toString();
    const iv =  CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(8).toString();

    // encrypt some bytes using GCM mode
    const cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-GCM', key);
    cipher.start({
        iv: iv, 
         additionalData: 'nvn', // optional
         tagLength: 128 // optional, defaults to 128 bits
    }); 
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(msg));
    cipher.finish();
    const encrypted = cipher.output;
    const encodedB64 = forge.util.encode64(encrypted.data);
    const tag = cipher.mode.tag; 
    const tagB64 = forge.util.encode64(tag.data);
    // outputs encrypted hex

    const trasmitmsg = key+iv+tagB64+encodedB64;
    return trasmitmsg
}
```

I have used CryptoJS to generate random string because random of node-forge giving nontransferable strings.

java code to decrypt this trasmitmsg is

```
public String getDecrypt(String transmsg) throws Exception {
    String keyString = transmsg.substring(0, 16);
    String ivString = transmsg.substring(16, 32);
    String additionalString = transmsg.substring(32, 56);
    String cipherString = transmsg.substring(56);

    byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes();
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    byte[] ivBytes = ivString.getBytes();

    byte[] one = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherString);
    byte[] two = Base64.getDecoder().decode(additionalString);
    byte[] cipherText = ArrayUtils.addAll(one, two);
    return decrypt(cipherText, key, ivBytes);
}

public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey key, byte[] IV) throws Exception {
    // Get Cipher Instance
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

    // Create SecretKeySpec
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");

    // Create GCMParameterSpec
    GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH , IV);

    // Initialize Cipher for DECRYPT_MODE
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);

    cipher.updateAAD("nvn".getBytes());
    byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

    return new String(decryptedText);
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: youre not using the pass parameter for encryption oO -
do you happen to have the decrypt in js as well ?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Did you figure it out ? He didn't use pass or "key" while sending the data. Can someone confirm ?

Comment: the pass is what goes into key 
in my case i had to do    
some hashing to get the real key:
var key = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(secret, salt, 65536, 32, 'sha256');